# How to prevent stopping IIS in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013 preview for web development.

When I click F5, the website is running. But when I press stop button in VS, it shuts down IIS server (in VS 2012 everything's fine). It's a huge inconvenience, cos every time you place minor changes to markup or whatever you have to press F5 instead of just click "Ctrl+S" and refresh the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to the `Enable edit and continue` option being checked by default in the Project Properties > Web > Debuggers section. Disabling it has solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the setup you are talking about. In order to do this, you can set up your project as follows:

- In your Project Properties, Select the Web tab
- Change the Start Action to "Don't open a page"

Now you can start your application using CTRL + F5 (start without debugging) to launch your application and use it without the debugger running. If you want the debugger, you can still hit F5 to start it up, but stopping debugging doesn't shut down the instance. It's great for making HTML changes in particular.

That said, I don't have "Enable Edit and Continue" checked either, as per Xaviers answer.